# What is wrong with my MathJax syntax below?

Tags: mathjax

This first (meaningless) equation renders fine (I am using this in MDWiki which encapsulates MathJax.

```
$$ EXP^{CN}_{i,t} = \alpha EXP^{CN}_t$$
```

This second (meaningless) equation fails, even though expression after \alpha follows exactly the same syntax as the expression to the left of the equal sign.

```
$$ EXP^{CN}_{i,t} = \alpha EXP^{CN}_{i,t}$$
```

I am expecting something that looks like this:

[image: Rendered result]

Comment: What do you mean "equation fails" because this works fine with proper implementation ~ https://www.mathjax.org/#demo or on mathoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the link and indeed it works there,  As indicated, I am using MDWiki to render markdown, It is supposed to support Mathjax, but obviously there is a glitch in the support.  I'll chase them down.

Comment: This is very likely due to markdown running first and replacing `_... _`  with italics, see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/html.html#interactions-with-content-management-systems for some info. Some markdown parsers can ignore TeX expressions, usually by requiring specific delimiters.